# Declaring a value in .vue file and using it again

Tags: vue.js

```
<span v-for="(indicator, i) in indicators" :key="indicator.id">
  {{ indicator.name }}
<span v-if="i !== indicators.length - 1"> vs </span>
```

Is there any way to save the value of indicator name in a variable and then using that somewhere else on .vue file?

Answer (score 0):

It works all fine like this:

```
{{indicatorName = indicator.name }}
```

and then use it as `{{indicatorName}}` in the code